# Form data is not getting displayed on 2nd page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, form-submit

This is the code of the page where data of form is supposed to display in a text box but its not even directing to this page and stays on the same page..page just blinks on click of submit and nothing else happens..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PayrollSystem
{
    public partial class frmPersonalVerified : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add your comments here
            txtVerifiedInfo.Text = Request["txtFirstName"] +
                "\n" + Request["txtLastName"] +
                "\n" + Request["txtPayRate"] +
                "\n" + Request["txtStartDate"] +
                "\n" + Request["txtEndDate"];
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code of submit button that I have on my other page that has a form with submit cancel buttons. Why is it not working? What's wrong?

```
.
.
.


 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            PostBackUrl="~/frmPersonalVerified.aspx" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
             PostBackUrl="~/frmMain.aspx"/>
        
        </asp:Panel>
```

I tried changing PostBackUrl="~/frmPersonalVerified.aspx"  to  PostBackUrl="frmPersonalVerified.aspx"  but it didnt work. What's wrong?

I also added a break point in the page load method of frmPersonalVerified page.. it doesn't go inside it.

Comment: is your page "frmPersonalVerified.aspx" is in any folder.I mean are you passing correct address of the page in PostBackUrl attribute of Submit button.

Comment: no..all files are in root folder of my website project

Comment: I do think it is the correct address else intellisense would show green line under the path,..isnt it? Its not showing green line

Comment: why are you posting to a different page? Is there a reason you could not access your data from codebehind

Comment: @codingbiz..thats the requirement of my assignment

Comment: If this is homework then tag it as homework

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for onclick event of submit button

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     Response.Redirect("~/frmPersonalVerified.aspx");

 }
```